# Apache redirect question to change domain name

Tags: apache

I am attempting to add a rewrite rule to my apache configuration file to redirect users to a new url.

The url of my site is https://openmind.scribesoftware.com. If a user enters a URL with https://openmind.scribesoft.com (note the lack of "ware") I'd like to redirect them as though they had typed the proper url.

I have tried a couple variations such as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^openmind\.scribesoft\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://openmind.scribesoftware.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However that results in the following error:

```
 This webpage has a redirect loop.

 The webpage at https://openmind.scribesoftware.com//enterprises/571 has resulted in too many redirects.
```

I already have a rewrite rule to redirect non-http requests to https requests and that is working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

HTTPS_HOST is not a real variable (see the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) docs). Use HTTP_HOST and HTTPS:

```
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^openmind\.scribesoftware\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Okay, my conf file now looks like:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^openmind\.scribesoft\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ="on"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://openmind.scribesoftware.com/$1 [R=301,L]
It now works without any errors...but it's also not redirecting when I navigate to https://openmind.scribesoft.com.

Comment: Apologies - the quotes aren't needed. Edited (and actually tried it this time).

Comment: This would have still resulted in a redirect loop. You should either remove the negation prefix (`!`) on the _CondPattern_ since you need to check that the request _matches_ the "other" hostname (not that it doesn't match). OR, keep the negation prefix and change the hostname to match the target hostname (so that anything other than the target is redirected).

Comment: @MrWhite Well spotted - can't believe this has been here for 8 years with nobody noticing that! Edited.